# Is it okay to set all divs overflow: hidden?

Tags: css

I guess I'm wondering if it is ill-advisable to just set:

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

... instead of worrying about clearing each div. Does anyone else do this or recommend for/against it? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I only ask because it seems like I have a handful of divs that require it, at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will set `overflow: hidden` for all `div`s. 
If you'll find it wrong for some part of your html, then you can disable it for any divs you'll need like this:

```
/* use default overflow for all divs in specific element */
#some-element-id div {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Or you can use classes for this.

Comment: Thanks. My main question is this a recommended method or not? I honestly don't see the harm, but maybe the pros know something I don't.

Comment: Well, I don't see anything bad here. Because you can always disable it for the part of html which don't need it.

Comment: Great, thanks! Just wanted to make sure before I go and hose everything up. =)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends if you want extra content to be hidden by default.  My personal preference is only to hide when I **know** it won't do any harm.  Consider a nav menu. If the user is working on a very small screen and you haven't *un*-hidden the nav menu overflow specifically, then that user won't be able to navigate.

What it comes down to is which is the worse outcome- broken layout or inaccessible content?